# How to automatically move the scroll bar on the listbox to show the selected item - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am selecting an Item in the Listbox dynamically. Now when the item is selected, the selected item has to be shown on the front-end of the listbox. More like the scroll-bar has to move to that item. So that the end user will get to know the item has been selected. I tried to use SetFocus but am getting an error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

The error occurs on line `.SetFocus(idx) = True` below:

```
ReqSearchvalue = Range("B" & reqrow).Value

Sheets("Main").Activate

With Sheets("Main").Ent_ListBox
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        Value = .List(i)
        If Value = ReqSearchvalue Then
            idx = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    .Selected(idx) = True
    .SetFocus(idx) = True
End With
```

Please kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: Is the list box an ActiveX control or a Form control ?

Comment: It is an ActiveX ListBox

Comment: You mean an ActiveX Listbox ? or are you using a button as well ?

Comment: What error are you getting?  And on what line?

Comment: It is an ActiveX ListBox. The error was Object doesn't support this property or method. The error was on the Line .SetFocus(idx)=True

Comment: .... going back here.... What about .Selected(idx) ONLY (without the = true)

Comment: @AnthonyHorne No sir, That gives the same error - Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: same case but for a single select listbox Form control , I select the item by code but I can't move scrollbar to the item's position, any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SetFocus` is not a method of the `ListBox`. You can however set the [`TopIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251776.aspx) property to do this:

```
With Sheets("Main").Ent_ListBox
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        Value = .List(i)
        If Value = ReqSearchvalue Then
            idx = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    .Selected(idx) = True
    .TopIndex = idx
End With
```